# Single time events in MVI architecture

Tags: android, architecture, kotlin, mosby

Trying new architecture paradigm where presenter creates immutable state(model) stream and view just renders it.

Can't understand how to handle situations where we need to make some event for the one time only. There are couple examples.

1) Notes app. We have `editText` and `saveButton`. User clicks `saveButton`, some processing happens and editText should be cleared. Could you guys please describe what will be in our `ViewState` here and approximate logic flow?

Questions and pitfalls I see now:

1. We subscribe to `editText.textChanges()` in presenter. If we will have `text` in our `ViewState` and render it each render call then we will fall into recursion because it will emit new textChange and will update state and render again.
2. Do we need `text` in `ViewState` to restore it on orientation text or process kill/restore, looks like it works out of box here. But imagine `recyclerView`s scroll position. We definitely need to save it to restore. We can't restore it on each render call cause it looks weird, isn't it?
3. If we consider such logic as side effect and will call `.doOnNext{ view.clearText() }` it makes sense, but do we have reference to view in canonical MVI implementation? Mosby doesn't have it as I see.
4. It makes sense but there is possibility of view being dead in the moment of `doOnNext` call. MVI should help us with this but only if it's the part of `ViewState`, right?

2) Github app. First screen(Org): `orgEditText`, `okButton`, `progressBar`. Second screen (Repos): `recyclerView`. When user enters organization into `orgEditText` and clicks `okButton` app should make request to API and on success navigate to Repos screen on success or show toast on failure. Again could you please describe `ViewState` for Org screen and what logic should look like?

Questions and pitfalls I see now:

1. We should show `progressBar` and disable `okButton` while loading. We should have like loading/content/error sealed class(lets call it `ContentState`) and have its instance in our `ViewState`. View knows how to render `ContentState.loading` and shows `progressBar` and disables `okButton`. Am I right?
2. How to handle navigation then? The same questions as 1.3 and 1.4.
3. I've seen opinions that navigation should be considered as side effect, but again 1.4.
4. Toast - is there something in state or we consider this as side effect? Same problems.

Google suggests `SingleLiveEvent` solution, but it looks weird and then there should be as much `LiveData<SingleLiveEvent>` streams as we have such things, not really a single source of truth.
Others suggest new intent generated from render func which is better but there is a possibility that some async operations will change state again and we'll get second Toast while first is showing and so on.

Comment: maybe [this](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby3-mvi-7) will help

Comment: This not helps, it is just a workaround for snackbar only and not some general solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Notes App:
In a perfect world: yes your ViewState would have an `text` changes whenever the user inserts the text and renders. Regarding the recursion: I might be wrong but I think that RxBindings somewhere offers an Observable that not only contains the changed text, but also a boolean flag if this change has been caused by user input or by programmatically setting the text. Anyways, I think you could also workaround the recursion if you check `if (editText.text != viewState.text)` and only set the text in case that they are different (keep in mind that you may have to use the TextWatcher callback that is triggered afterward text has been changed to start the intent, not "before is going to be changed").

With that said, on Android we are not living in a perfect world. As you have already said, the text will be restore automatically by android. Therefore it makes sense to not make text part of the ViewState.

So it sounds that in that case the ViewState is just an enum like this:

```
enum ViewState {
   // The user can type typing text
   IDLING,

   // The app is saving the note
   PROCESSING,

   // After having saved (PROCESSING) the note, CLEARED means, show a new empty note  
   CLEARED
}
```

So the initial state is `IDLING`. Then once the note should be saved the next emitted ViewState is `PROCESSING`. Once this was successful, your business logic immediately fires a `CLEARED` followed immediately by  `IDLING` so at the end the user sees an empty note again and can start typing the new note.

Don't use `doOnNext()` for manipulating the view. ViewState is the single source of truth for the view.

Regarding RecyclerView: RecyclerView restores it's scroll position automatically, if not (you set the LayoutManager and  / or adapter to late, after state has been restored). Nevertheless, if you would like to model the scroll position in ViewState, which again in a perfect world would be the best solution I guess, you should consider not update the scroll position in your ViewState on each pixel scrolled but rather do it once the user is not scrolling anymore / fling has finished.

2) Github app:

> 1. We should show progressBar and disable okButton while loading. We
>      should have like loading/content/error sealed class(lets call it
>      ContentState) and have its instance in our ViewState. View knows how
>      to render ContentState.loading and shows progressBar and disables
>      okButton. Am I right?

Yes

> 2. How to handle navigation then?

For me, handling this as a side effect works well: I have a class `Navigator` that is injected into the presenter and used in `doOnNext { navigator.goToX() }` . The Navigator then dispatches that to another component that can be temporarily attached / detached. So this other component is observing the Navigator for "navigation events" The reason why I would do that is that then this component is not leaking activity / fragment context. "This component" can be directly the Activity or Fragment or whatever, but I tend to have a dedicated class, let's call it `Router` that observes the `Navigator` for navigation events and does the  `FragmentTransactions` or whatever you use in your app.

> 4. Toast - is there something in state or we consider this as side effect? Same problems.

This can be handled similar to what you can do with `Snackbar` (see [here](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby3-mvi-7)). Toast doesn't have an API to hide a Toast. So instead of a timer you can immediately fire two ViewState one after another: the first one with the error flag set (which then causes the Toast do be displayed on screen) and the second one where you "clear" this flag. Something like this:

```
Observable.just( ViewState(error = true, ...), new ViewState( error = false, ... )
```

I hope that clarifies some things, but as always: Don't take them as a silverbullet. Do whatever works best for your app and use case. Don't be super religious, it's always a case by case decision.

Comment: Thanks for such a big answer. That double state emitting one right after another looks like a good generic solution for these situations. How do you think it should be done, our presenter has scan which emits only one ViewState, we need something like two consecutive Actions/PartialStates whatever, first one to start doing something flag, second one to clear this flag, right? But there is still possible gap between these emits where some other state change can happen, isn't it?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but the state reducer (`scan()` operator) takes care that at the end you get the correct viewstate out.

Comment: I mean in the end it doesn't matter, yes, but if we have Toast showing on some "showError" bool flag from our state equals true and another action will lead to new state before clear action reduced then two Toasts will be shown which is obviously not looks right.

Comment: zour scan() gets the "showError action" and the output is a ViewState with showError = true. Next "another action" comes (before "clear error action" is handled): In that case the scan() operator know that ViewState.showError == true and set it to false. that prevents the second toast to appear on screen. Next the "clear error action" is handled by the scan() operator and since showError is already set to false,output is still a ViewState with showError == false. That is the beauty of a state reducer: It ensures that you get the correct state as output regardless of the order the inputs happen

Comment: @sockeqwe why would you even need "clear error action" when state reducer will know that it needs to clear error flag?